# Nested tables with BIRT from XML Data Source

Tags: xml, xpath, birt, xpath-2.0

I'm trying to reproduce a report,with BIRT, of this kind:

### Scenario:

- I have a list of items (let's say prduct categories).
- Each item (or category) have a fixed number of tables (let's say, the table of the product_id vs sold_sold quantity, and a table with some information about the category)
- Each table inside a category have a variable number of rows.

### Data structure:

I read data from an `XML`, let's say it is something like this:

```
<list>
     <item>
          <table1>
              <row>
                  <column1>item 1 table 1 row 1 col 1</column1>
                  <column2>item 1 table 1 row 1 col 2</column2>
              </row>
              <row>
                  <column1>item 1 table 1 row 2 col 1</column1>
                  <column2>item 1 table 1 row 2 col 2</column2>
              </row>
          </table1>
          <table2>
              <row>
                  <columnX>item 1 table 2 row 1 col 1</columnX>
                  <columnY>item 1 table 2 row 1 col 2</columnY>
                  <columnZ>item 1 table 2 row 1 col </columnZ>
              </row>
              <row>
                  <columnX>item 1 table 2 row 2 col 1</columnX>
                  <columnY>item 1 table 2 row 2 col 2</columnY>
                  <columnZ>item 1 table 2 row 2 col 3</columnZ>
              </row>
          </table2>
    </item>
    <item>
    .
    .
    </item>
```

### Desidered result:

So I'm trying to reproduce this:

```
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|  column 1                 |  column 2                 |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|item 1 table 1 row 1 col 1 |item 1 table 1 row 1 col 2 |
|item 1 table 1 row 2 col 1 |item 1 table 1 row 2 col 2 |
.
|item 1 table 1 row N1 col 1|item 1 table 1 row N1 col 2|
+---------------------------+---------------------------+

+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|  column X                 |  column Y                 |  column Z                 |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|item 1 table 2 row 1 col 1 |item 1 table 2 row 1 col 2 |item 1 table 2 row 1 col 3 |
|item 1 table 2 row 2 col 1 |item 1 table 2 row 2 col 2 |item 1 table 2 row 2 col 3 |
.
|item 1 table 2 row N2 col 1|item 1 table 2 row N2 col 2|item 1 table 2 row N2 col 3|
+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+

.
.
.

+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|  column 1                 |  column 2                 |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|item K table 1 row 1 col 1 |item K table 1 row 1 col 2 |
|item K table 1 row 2 col 1 |item K table 1 row 2 col 2 |
.
|item K table 1 row N1 col 1|item K table 1 row N1 col 2|
+---------------------------+---------------------------+

+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|  column X                 |  column Y                 |  column Z                 |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|item K table 2 row 1 col 1 |item K table 2 row 1 col 2 |item 1 table 2 row 1 col 3 |
|item K table 2 row 2 col 1 |item K table 2 row 2 col 2 |item 1 table 2 row 2 col 3 |
.
|item K table 2 row N2 col 1|item k table 2 row N2 col 2|item 1 table 2 row N2 col 3|
+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
```

### Experiment 1

I admit I am new to `BIRT`. This is what I have tried so far:

#### Importing:

- Import the XML file in the Data Soruce
- New DataSet, I imported the `list` item as `/list/` (fixed aboslute path) (called `DataSet`)
  And imported `column1` and `column X` (just becouse I had to import something):
  ** This means that the dataset will take the value of the first row of these table.
- I then added the varoious tables (with relative path) and added their column. Each table is a different DataSet. (called `DataSet1`,`DataSet2`,`DataSet3`)

#### Data:

- I made a table with 4 columns:

  - first column contains `column1` of the list (which is the first value of the following table)
- second column contains a table:

  - this table contains `column 1` and `column2`
- third column contains another table

  - this table contains `columnX`,`columnY` and `columnZ` as columns.

#### Result:

As result I get that:

- For each row in `<item>` I get a row
- for each row, the nested tables *ALWAYS* have the same rows!

  - instead, I want that they get only rows from the current item `<item>`

Any idea? thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you used a table? The behavior you are describing sounds like you may have used a 'grid" instead of a 'table'

Comment: Yes tables.. I guess I have to set somwehre that the nested table is made only of `comlumn1` elements inside the _outer_ table, but no idea how.

Comment: Do you think that could it be an Xpath related stuff?